# pandas ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: python, pandas

I have 20 df (named sample1...sample20) and each df is loaded using,

```
sample1 = pd.read_table('pathtosample1.csv', sep='\t', index_col=0)["score"]
```

I again load each file with a different variable for the meta step below,

```
meta1 = pd.read_table('pathtosample1.csv', sep='\t', index_col=0).loc[:,['junction_id','splice_site','intron_size', 'anchor','genes','transcripts', 'exons_skipped']]
```

sample1 df

```
Unique  junction_id score   splice_site anchor  intron_size exons_skipped   genes   transcripts
3:107915006-107915391(-)    ENSMUSG00000000001:E001 1017    GT-AG   DA  386 0   Gnai3   ENSMUST00000000001
3:107912225-107912321(-)    ENSMUSG00000000001:E002 10  GT-AG   D   97  0   Gnai3   ENSMUST00000000001
3:107912234-107912321(-)    ENSMUSG00000000001:E003 979 GT-AG   DA  88  0   Gnai3   ENSMUST00000000001
3:107912530-107914853(-)    ENSMUSG00000000001:E004 996 GT-AG   DA  2324    0   Gnai3   ENSMUST00000000001
3:107912530-107915391(-)    ENSMUSG00000000001:E005 3   GT-AG   NDA 2862    1   Gnai3   ENSMUST00000000001
3:107915520-107918681(-)    ENSMUSG00000000001:E006 1113    GT-AG   DA  3162    0   Gnai3   ENSMUST00000000001
3:107915520-107921219(-)    ENSMUSG00000000001:E007 1   GT-AG   NDA 5700    1   Gnai3   ENSMUST00000000001
3:107915520-107915944(-)    ENSMUSG00000000001:E008 1   GT-AG   A   425 0   Gnai3   ENSMUST00000000001
3:107918809-107921219(-)    ENSMUSG00000000001:E009 1141    GT-AG   DA  2411    0   Gnai3   ENSMUST00000000001
```

for representation I use these commands indicating only 6 samples

```
concat =  pd.concat([sample1,sample2,sample3,sample4,sample5,sample6], axis=1).fillna(0)
concat.columns = ["score_1", "score_2", "score_3","score_4", "score_5", "score_6"]
meta = pd.concat([meta1,meta2,meta3,meta4,meta5,meta6], ignore_index=True)

meta = meta[~meta.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
concat = pd.concat([concat, meta], axis=1)
concat.to_csv('data.csv')
```

The error i get is,

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

my expected output is to 1st get all the elements in first column from all files and add the score against each sample in a column and then add rest of the meta columns corresponding to each row, expected output

```
Junction_id score1  score2  score3  score4 score5 score6    Unique  splice_site intron_size anchor  genes   transcripts exons_skipped
ENSMUSG00000000001:E001 1017    1   1651    6   3   1   3:107915006-107915391(-)    GT-AG   386 DA  Gnai3   ENSMUST00000000001  0
ENSMUSG00000000001:E002 10  7   3   1144    1193    895 3:107912225-107912321(-)    GT-AG   97  D   Gnai3   ENSMUST00000000001  0
ENSMUSG00000000001:E003 979 1075    1588    923 1223    1017    3:107912234-107912321(-)    GT-AG   88  DA  Gnai3   ENSMUST00000000001  0
ENSMUSG00000000001:E004 996 3   1522    1   1   2   3:107912530-107914853(-)    GT-AG   2324    DA  Gnai3   ENSMUST00000000001  0
ENSMUSG00000000001:E005 3   1759    14  1127    4   1112    3:107912530-107915391(-)    GT-AG   2862    NDA Gnai3   ENSMUST00000000001  1
```

not sure which step is causing this error

Comment: You might have indexes with the same value in different samples

Comment: the score or the index itself?

Comment: The index itself. These need to be unique

Comment: You specify `axis=1` on all `concat` except for `meta = pd.concat(...)`, is that argument intentionally left out for that case?  Which line is throwing the `ValueError`?

Comment: good catch, will put axis =1

Comment: Did `axis=1` resolve your issue?